# How can I change my script so it minimizes the cost, and at the same time calculates the volume and weight chosen is viable?

Tags: python, pandas, pulp, bin-packing

I created a function using pulp which takes in an array of items and of trucks.  Each item has a capacity, and every truck has a capacity and a cost. I used a pulp solver to calculate the minimum number of trucks required, whilst keeping the minimum cost. The constraining factor is the capacity, and the optimizing factor is the bin cost. But now, I want to add another constraining factor of volume. Can it be done ? Can you suggest a way to do this using the solver itself ?? I am trying to do that part without using the solver, but it is not helping at all. Thanks a lot.

I tried to create a function to which replaces the minimum truck with the next largest truck whenever I get the message, "Trucks not sufficient"

UPDATE: @kabdulla helped me get the answer, but also pointed that it has a big flaw that it only takes into consideration the whole volume of items rather than geometry of the items to fit inside; a 2 X 2 X 2 item should fit in a truck easily, but a 8 X 1 X 1 has a different geometry and has different constraints. Here is my updated code(all thanks to @kabdulla ) with item and truck details.

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np

# Item details
item_name = ["Mudguard1","Mudguard2","Mudguard3","Mudguard4",]
item_id = ["1001474185","1001474401","1001474182","1001474154"]
item_length = [14,22,16,16]
item_breadth = [12,24,14,12]
item_height = [9,26,12,17]
item_quantity = [14,8,10,1]
item_vol = [12.25,63.55,15.55,1.88]
item_mass= [160,528,83,5]
n_items = len(item_id)
set_items = range(n_items)

# Details of trucks
item_name = ["Tata-407-9.5","Tata-407-13","Tata-407-17","Tata-407-16",]
item_id = ["1","2","3","4"]
truck_length = [14,22,16,16]
truck_breadth = [12,24,14,12]
truck_height = [9,26,12,17]
truck_quantity = [14,8,10,1]
truck_vol = [12.25,63.55,15.55,1.88]
truck_mass= [160,528,83,5]
truck_cost = [7,1.5,18,100]


n_trucks = len(truck_cost)
set_trucks = range(n_trucks)

y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('truckUsed', set_trucks,
    lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('itemInTruck', (set_items, set_trucks), 
    lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

# Model formulation
prob = LpProblem("Truck allocation problem", LpMinimize)

# Objective
prob += lpSum([truck_cost[i] * y[i] for i in set_trucks])

# Constraints
for j in set_items:
    # Every item must be taken in one truck
    prob += lpSum([x[j][i] for i in set_trucks]) == 1

for i in set_trucks:
    # Respect the mass constraint of trucks
    prob += lpSum([item_mass[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_mass[i]*y[i]

    # Respect the volume constraint of trucks
    prob += lpSum([item_vol[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_vol[i]*y[i]

# Ensure y variables have to be set to make use of x variables:
for j in set_items:
    for i in set_trucks:
        x[j][i] <= y[i]


prob.solve()

x_soln = np.array([[x[i][j].varValue for i in set_items] for j in set_trucks])
y_soln = np.array([y[i].varValue for i in set_trucks])

print (("Status:"), LpStatus[prob.status])
print ("Total Cost is: ", value(prob.objective))
print("x_soln"); print(x_soln)
print("y_soln"); print(y_soln)

print("Trucks used: " + str(sum(([y_soln[i] for i in set_trucks]))))

for i in set_items:
    for j in set_trucks:
        if x[i][j].value() == 1:
            print("Item " + str(i) + " is packed in vehicle "+ str(j))

totalitemvol = sum(item_vol)

totaltruckvol = sum([y[i].value() * truck_vol[i] for i in set_trucks])
print("Volume of used trucks is " + str(totaltruckvol))

if(totaltruckvol >= totalitemvol):
  print("Trucks are sufficient")
else:
  print("Items cannot fit")
```

This is my output:

```
Status: Optimal
Total Cost is:  126.5
x_soln
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
y_soln
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
Trucks used: 4.0
Item 0 is packed in vehicle 0
Item 1 is packed in vehicle 1
Item 2 is packed in vehicle 2
Item 3 is packed in vehicle 3
The volume of used trucks is 93.22999999999999
Trucks are sufficient
```

Here is a colab link to play around.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uKuS2F4Xd1Lbps8yAwivLbhzZrD_Hv0-

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. What results do you get from your attempt above, and what do you expect to get? In essence you should have one constraint per truck that ensure the sum of weights carried are within weight allowance, and the sum of volume carried are within volume allowance - as long as you don't also want to solve the bin-packing problem (ensuring volume less than capacity doesn't ensure the items actually fit - they could be very thin and too long for the truck for example).

Comment: Thank you for your query. I have updated with the results I get, and a colab playground link. I want the code to take into consideration the volume (_binVol_) of the trucks, and then give me the final answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of the code below assumes there is a total carrying mass, and a total carrying volume constraint on each truck. NB: this does not guarantee a combination of items which fit within trucks (an item which is 8m x 1m x 1m is 8 cubic meters in volume, but would not fit in a truck whose internal space was 2m x 2m x 2m = 8 cubic meters for example, but using the volume constraint below this would not violate the constraint).

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np

# Item masses, volumes
item_mass = [16, 10, 5]
item_vol = [25, 12, 1]
n_items = len(item_vol)
set_items = range(n_items)

# Mass & volume capacities of trucks
truck_mass = [7, 15, 15, 15, 18, 38, 64, 100]
truck_vol = [25, 50, 50, 50, 100, 125, 250, 500]

# Cost of using each truck
truck_cost = [7, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 18, 380, 640, 1000]

n_trucks = len(truck_cost)
set_trucks = range(n_trucks)

y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('truckUsed', set_trucks,
    lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('itemInTruck', (set_items, set_trucks), 
    lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

# Model formulation
prob = LpProblem("Truck allocatoin problem", LpMinimize)

# Objective
prob += lpSum([truck_cost[i] * y[i] for i in set_trucks])

# Constraints
for j in set_items:
    # Every item must be taken in one truck
    prob += lpSum([x[j][i] for i in set_trucks]) == 1

for i in set_trucks:
    # Respect the mass constraint of trucks
    prob += lpSum([item_mass[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_mass[i]*y[i]

    # Respect the volume constraint of trucks
    prob += lpSum([item_vol[j] * x[j][i] for j in set_items]) <= truck_vol[i]*y[i]

# Ensure y variables have to be set to make use of x variables:
for j in set_items:
    for i in set_trucks:
        x[j][i] <= y[i]


prob.solve()

x_soln = np.array([[x[i][j].varValue for i in set_items] for j in set_trucks])
y_soln = np.array([y[i].varValue for i in set_trucks])

print (("Status:"), LpStatus[prob.status])
print ("Total Cost is: ", value(prob.objective))
print("x_soln"); print(x_soln)
print("y_soln"); print(y_soln)

print("Trucks used: " + str(sum(([y_soln[i] for i in set_trucks]))))

for i in set_items:
    for j in set_trucks:
        if x[i][j].value() == 1:
            print("Item " + str(i) + " is packed in vehicle "+ str(j))

totalitemvol = sum(item_vol)

totaltruckvol = sum([y[i].value() * truck_vol[i] for i in set_trucks])
print("Volume of used trucks is " + str(totaltruckvol))

if(totaltruckvol >= totalitemvol):
  print("Trucks are sufficient")
else:
  print("Items cannot fit")
```

Which should return the following:

```
('Status:', 'Optimal')
('Total Cost is: ', 19.5)
x_soln
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
y_soln
[0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
Trucks used: 2.0
Item 0 is packed in vehicle 4
Item 1 is packed in vehicle 3
Item 2 is packed in vehicle 3
Volume of used trucks is 150.0
Trucks are sufficient
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I had a doubt though, is there a way to remove the constraint where every item can only be put in a single truck ? Did you remove that because it will turn the problem into NP-hard ? Thing is, the code is losing a lot of optimization i.e. if I ask the script to pack 2 items of weight 12,25 and 500, the code correctly packs the 500 into the 500 truck, *but*, it packs the 12 and the 25 into 50 and 100 trucks which is very inefficient.

Comment: Can you share the example data which is giving you unexpected results? The code shown above will choose the lower cost combination of trucks which satisfy the volume and mass constraints to carry the packages, based only on total truck cost. If you have another objective (such as reducing the number of separate trucks) you will need to add to the objective function.

Comment: I have updated and shared a colab link to play around. I did not understand what did you mean when you said _but using the volume constraint below this would not violate the constraint_ . Is there any possible way to somehow make sure the items do fit in a truck by weight, volume and also the geometry ?

Comment: That's a 3D bin packing problem and if you google that you will find some solutions in papers and there might be example code out there as well. It's worth noting that it is computationally quite intensive for large numbers of objects - you have to chose the relative orientations and positions of objects as well as their allocations to trucks - so lots of integer decision variables.

Comment: I really tried finding it, but could not find anything....many libraries like pyshipping got very close, but none of them were able to solve my problem taking into all the constraints my problem had. Thanks anyways!